# What is the difference between a public and private interface in Java

Tags: java

I know the difference between all the access modifiers in Java. However, someone asked me a very interesting question that I struggled to find the answer to: What is the difference between a `private` interface and a `public` interface in Java, in particular, **how it is used as a class member**? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's analogous to the difference between a `private` and `public` class.

Comment: What does analogous mean?

Comment: [This link](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/privateInterface.pdf) might be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe we all know the use of `public interface`, so I would mention the point of `private/protected interface` here.

`Interfaces` can be members of class definitions and can be declared `private` or `protected` there.

```
public class Test {  

    private interface Sortable {  
    }  

   protected interface Searchable {  
    }  

}
```

**[Example 1: -- Source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/254867/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/interface-private-protected)**

```
public class PrivateInterface {  
     private interface InnerInterface {  
          void f();  
     }  

     private class InnerClass1 implements InnerInterface {  
           public void f() {   
               System.out.println("From InnerClass1");  
           }  
     }  

     private class InnerClass2 implements InnerInterface {  
           public void f() {   
               System.out.println("From InnerClass2");  
           }  
     }  

     public static void main(String[] args) {  
          PrivateInterface pi = new PrivateInterface();  
          pi.new InnerClass1().f();  
          pi.new InnerClass2().f();  
     }  
}   

/* Output: 
From InnerClass1 
From InnerClass2 
*/
```

> It's the interface itself that can be package-private, not the methods
>   in it. You can define an interface that can only be used (by name)
>   within the package it's defined in, but its methods are public like
>   all interface methods. If a class implements that interface, the
>   methods it defines must be public. The key thing here is that it's the
>   interface type that isn't visible outside the package, not the
>   methods.

Comment: +1 I learn something new everyday. Can't say I've ever thought of putting an `interface` as a class member.

Answer (score 0):

The `public`, `private`, and `protected` access modifiers on an interface mean the same thing that they mean on a class.  I typically see these modifiers used on an interface that is nested in a class.  Something like [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/254867/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/interface-private-protected):

```
//: interfaces/RandomWords.java  
// Implementing an interface to conform to a method.  
package interfaces;  

public class PrivateInterface {  
  private interface InnerInterface {  
        void f();  
  }  

  private class InnerClass1 implements InnerInterface {  
         public void f() {   
             System.out.println("From InnerClass1");  
         }  
  }  

  private class InnerClass2 implements InnerInterface {  
         public void f() {   
             System.out.println("From InnerClass2");  
         }  
  }  

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
        PrivateInterface pi = new PrivateInterface();  
        pi.new InnerClass1().f();  
        pi.new InnerClass2().f();  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface declaration may include these access modifiers:

```
public protected private abstract static strictfp
```

**public:** If an interface type is declared public,then it can be accessed by any code.

**protected/private:** The access modifiers protected and private pertain only to member interfaces within a directly enclosing class declaration. A `member interface` is an interface whose declaration is directly enclosed in another class or interface declaration.

**static:** The access modifier `static` pertains only to member interfaces, not to top level interfaces.

**abstract:** Every interface is implicitly `abstract`. This modifier is obsolete and should not
be used in new programs.

**strictfp:** The effect of the `strictfp` modifier is to make all float or double expressions
within the interface declaration be explicitly [FP-strict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp).

Ref: [Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)